# How to match an edge launch SMA connector to a pcb with coplanar waveguide with ground?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, connector

I'm trying to develop a pcb that is capable of handling signals over 6GHz and created a test board to see how the pcb and connectors perform. The pcb is a relatively low-cost 4-layer FR-4 TG155 board with impedance matching spec of JLC04161H-7628. The GCPW specs are 0.35mm track surrounded by 0.6mm margin on each side. The results were subpar and really only handled signals below 2GHz properly. My question is how can I find a decent SMA edge connector (at a reasonable price) that will not only match the physical dimensions (i.e. board thickness and pin width), and not cause the reflections seen below. I've found many reasonably priced connectors on digikey, but they always reference a different board thickness, center pin pad width, and/or board material (e.g. Rogers $$$). Is there a way I could figure out how to adapt the design to my pcb materials? I have noticed JLC has added PTFE boards now at a reasonable price. I would consider that, if useful, however it is only 2-layer, so in that case I would need to have separate boards for RF and logic components.

Another interesting thing I noticed, is I took the pcb out of the equation and soldered two edge-launch connectors together directly and also noticed poor performance, albeit slightly better. I'm not sure if that says anything about the connector or if the lack of performance was due to not using as directed.

Here is the pcb design with a center pin diameter larger than the transmission line track width:
[image: PCB with SMA edge-launch]

Here is the performance tested using a libre VNA (S21 + S22 VSWR):
[image: S21 + S22 VSWR]

And this is (S21 + S11 VSWR):
[image: S21 + S11 VSWR]

Lastly, here is the performance of the 2 connectors soldered together directly (S21 + S22 VSWR):
[image: Bridged - S21 + S22 VSWR]

(S21 + S22 imp):
[image: Bridged - S21 + S22 imp]

Comment: You really need a 3-D field solver to do this right.  Even small changes in trace width, trace to via spacing, via-to-via spacing, etc can cause issues at your frequency.

Comment: Could you please put the part number of the connector you are using in the question? I also notice that your coplanar ground plane gets closer to the track around the pad where it is wider. This further lowers the characteristic impedance here, in addition to the wider track, because of the added capacitance of the closer coplanar ground. For matching purposes you probably want to open up the coplanar ground plane abit around the pad

Comment: I wasn't sure what was more important, the pad width or the spacing around it. So you're saying the spacing around the center pad should match the rest of the track? The connectors were a cheap set from Amazon. No specs provided. I didn't think it would be a huge issue, and I'd like to understand this better before throwing a lot of money on branded connectors at $10 a pop. Really trying to feel confident I can look at a spec sheet and adapt it to my board with confidence. From my test board, seems like the filters, tracks and miters are fine; it's just the transition from connector to board.

Comment: Making the pad wider is going to lower its impedance.  Reducing the spacing between the pad and the adjacent vias is going to lower the pad's impedance.